# Why does Oracle execute both TABLE SCAN and INDEX UNIQUE SCAN on the same table in one query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I am not looking for a optimization of the following, just an explanation. I have this query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(LARGE_A.id_a), SUM(LARGE_A.b_integer)
FROM LARGE_A
INNER JOIN MEDIUM_A ON LARGE_A.id_a = MEDIUM_A.id
INNER JOIN MEDIUM_B ON LARGE_A.id_b = MEDIUM_B.id
WHERE
    MEDIUM_A.a_varchar2 LIKE 'Example%' AND
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MEDIUM_B.a_datetime) = 2000 AND
    LARGE_A.a_integer BETWEEN 0 AND 1000;
```

The types of attributes are written in their names. IDs are integers. The table `LARGE_A` has 1 000 000 rows, the medium ones have 100 000 each. IDs are primary keys, however table `LARGE_A` has a compound key `(id_a, id_b)`.

Then I've got the following execution plan taken from `V$SQL` view because Autotrace lies about this one.

```
SELECT STATEMENT                        
|SORT AGGREGATE                         
||HASH JOIN                             
|||NESTED LOOPS                         
||||NESTED LOOPS                        
|||||STATISTICS COLLECTOR               
||||||NESTED LOOPS                      
|||||||TABLE ACCESS FULL                LARGE_A
|||||||TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      MEDIUM_A
||||||||INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               PK(MEDIUM_A)
|||||INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  PK(MEDIUM_B)
||||TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         MEDIUM_B
|||TABLE ACCESS FULL                    MEDIUM_B
```

PK means non-clustered index on the primary key (an integer) of the table given in parenthesis. I don't use IOTs here.

Why would the optimizer first query records one by one from the index `PK(MEDIUM_B)` then fetch the rest of the rows using ROWID and then run the FULL table scan again?

Comment: Updating your question with the SQL statement you’re running would be helpful

Comment: @NickW Here you go.

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but this: `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MEDIUM_B.a_datetime) = 0` is pointless. Year can not be 0 (in Oracle). If you try it, e.g. `to_date('01.01.0000', 'dd.mm.yyyy')` you'll get `ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0`. So, if you really have that condition, just remove it as it can never be true.

Comment: @Littlefoot Sorry, I'll fix it. In the real query, there is of course a year from modern times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is a *full* plan, not the *actual* plan (in `v$sql`, the difference between `full_plan_hash_value` and `plan_hash_value`). Since 12c, Oracle has adaptive plans, giving it the ability to change from one plan to another mid-flight if it sees at runtime that its cardinality guesses are way off. The full plan gives both options - either a hash join + full scan of table B, or a nested loops + index access of table B. It all depends on how many rows it gets from table A as to which is the best plan.

You can see this best this way:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ....
/
SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display(format=>'ADAPTIVE'))
/
```

You will see `-` marks next to the disabled plan lines, the one's that wont' be used by default... but they are still part of the plan so that if Oracle decides mid-execution to switch, it can enable those lines and disable the original defaults. To see what is actually being used by your code at runtime, you have to observe it by getting `v$session.sql_id / sql_child_number`, then do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display_cursor([sqlid],[childnumber]))

/
```

Comment: So Autotrace displays the correct plan? The one that is actually executed as the last one (changed to mid-flight)?

Comment: No, autotrace is showing you the full plan, which includes steps that are disabled and won't be used. You will almost certainly get the nested loops + index access to tableB and the full table scan + hash join won't be used. I suggest using dbms_xplan, not autotrace in the future.